# PostgreSQL - Open source monitoring tool for windows (without Apache)

Tags: database, postgresql, monitoring

I am looking for a tool to do some monitoring on my local postgres database. I want to know if the slowness of some queries is caused by the poor performance of the machine CPU/memory or if it's caused by postgres itself.

I have found pgwatch as an interesting real-time monitoring tool, but you need to install it on Apache server with PHP server (as far as I know). I just want to monitor the database in local. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pgadmin3, i don't know if they have a monitoring tool, but don't use apache.

Comment: I already use pgAdmin but I have not found a real-time monitoring tool in it.